# Java send image from client to server

Tags: java, image, client, host

Im coding a little program and i want the client to take a printscreen and then send the image to the server they are connected to.

Heres the client code.

```
public void run() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage PrintScreen = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        //what do I do here?!?!?!
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the server code

```
public void run() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Read image sent from client.


        //Sleep shit
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hopefully you can help me. I've tried to google to get my answer but there are some things i don't really understand. I've seen people converting the image to an array of bytes. Why do you have to do this?

Comment: You need to set up a socket connection and send through the image as an array of bytes...  If you haven't learnt anything about sockets yet, it might be worth reading into simple data transfer before you start sending files.

Comment: I've done that already, im just showing the threads that will send and get data.

Comment: Read the image into a byte array, send the length of the byte array to the server so that it knows how much data to expect, then have the server wait for say 8192 bytes, write them to a file, wait for 8192, write... repeat that until the file size is equal to the size sent by the client.

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into it tomorrow!

Comment: This depends.  How are you connecting to the server?

Comment: I made the assumption he was using TCP in my commment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-in-java/), to see how to transfer `BufferedImage` vie Streams, [This](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) to see how to send data from client to server(if have any problems with it), and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/) to see how to create image on server side.